# How can I link to an image in ROOT/app/assets/images before precompile?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, path

I'm trying to use html to render an image before precompiling my assets, which moves all images into the public folder.

This code: `<img src="Flower.jpg">` point to this path: `<RAILS ROOT>/public/app/assets/images/Flower.jpg`

How can I write html to link here: `<RAILS ROOT>/app/assets/images/Flower.jpg`? It has to be posssible, because rendering it with erb works just fine: `<%=image_tag("Flower.jpg")%>`.

I tried writing out the full path like this: `<img src="/app/assets/images/Flower.jpg">` but that code doesn't show anything.

I also tried using the exact rails console printout of `helper.image_tag("Flower.jpg")`, which was this:

```
<img alt=\"Flower\" src=\"/assets/Flower.jpg\" />
```

But that code doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I learned that this html works to access images in the App folder:

```
<img src="/assets/Flower.jpg">
```

but that isn't very helpful, because a precompile moves all the images, so that code would no longer use the right path after deployment. So if I put the relevant images into my Public folder before precompile, I can link to them like this:

```
<img src="/Flower.jpg">
```

and that path will work both before and after precompilation.

Answer (score 0):

The "app" part of the link is not needed:

```
<img src="assets/images/Flower.jpg"
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. The space where the image should be is just blank. Do you know of a way I can debug this?

Comment: The assets pipeline is hard to debug. It may be configured wrong. If you are in development, you should have config.serve.static_assets = true, for example.